# apt-add-repository doesn't work on debian 12

Tags: debian

When I try to add non-free on debian 12 (bookworm) with apt-add-repository nothing happens. This used to work on bullseye. I guess the reason is that package source files changed format. Old format was:

`deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main`

New format

```
Types: deb
# http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20230703T000000Z
URIs: http://deb.debian.org/debian
Suites: bookworm bookworm-updates
Components: main
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg
```

When I run apt-add-repository the file doesn't change. No new components are added.

```
# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
# apt-add-repository -y non-free
Adding component(s) 'non-free' to all repositories.
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.sources 
Types: deb
# http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20230703T000000Z
URIs: http://deb.debian.org/debian
Suites: bookworm bookworm-updates
Components: main
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg

Types: deb
# http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20230703T000000Z
URIs: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security
Suites: bookworm-security
Components: main
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Is there any solution to that apart from manually editing the debian.sources file?

Comment: Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about system configuration, not about __programming__, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It _might_ be suitable for [sf] or [unix.se]: consult the Help Centre for the site before you post.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this recently, I am unsure as to why this happens. I have a feeling this a bug.
Either way I got around this by manually adding and setting the non-free source list repository.

Add the new repository and update your apt cache database.

```
sudo echo "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian bookworm main non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/non-free.list
sudo apt update
```

Make sure to set the mirror list closest to you for best performance.

https://www.debian.org/mirror/list