# Error while installing sudo apt install libc6:i386 on Debian 12 bookworm on pi5

Tags: ubuntu, debian, steam

OS:  Raspbian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
I wanted to install steamcmd with it gives this issue:

```
steamcmd:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.12) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libstdc++6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
```

So when I try to install libc6 then shows up.
Tried this method: [apt-add-repository doesn't work on debian 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76688863/apt-add-repository-doesnt-work-on-debian-12)
I tried every method to install these packages but unable to do so. Also considered to downgrade the packages that are confilicting but not sure how to because don't know the exact versions of the packages that needs to be downgraded

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gpgv or
                gpgv2 but it is not going to be installed or
                gpgv1
       Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: raspbian-archive-keyring but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
       Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.5) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libseccomp2 (>= 2.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsystemd0
       Recommends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
 base-files : PreDepends: awk
 base-passwd : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
               Depends: libdebconfclient0 (>= 0.145) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 bash : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.36) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: libtinfo6 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
 bsdutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
            PreDepends: libsystemd0
            Recommends: bsdextrautils
 coreutils : PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libattr1 (>= 1:2.4.44) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
             PreDepends: libgmp10 (>= 2:6.2.1+dfsg1) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 dash : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 debianutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 diffutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 dpkg : PreDepends: libbz2-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: liblzma5 (>= 5.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libmd0 (>= 0.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libzstd1 (>= 1.5.2) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
 e2fsprogs : PreDepends: libblkid1 (>= 2.36) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
             PreDepends: libcom-err2 (>= 1.43.9) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libext2fs2 (= 1.47.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libss2 (>= 1.38) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: logsave
             Recommends: e2fsprogs-l10n but it is not going to be installed
 findutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
             PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 grep : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: libpcre2-8-0 (>= 10.32) but it is not going to be installed
 gzip : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but it is not installable
 hostname : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv or
                    sysvinit-core but it is not installable
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.36) but it is not installable
            Depends: libc6 (< 2.37) but it is not installable
 libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libidn2-0:i386 (>= 2.0.5~) but it is not going to be installed
 libcrypt1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.36) but it is not installable
 libgcc-s1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 login : PreDepends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
         PreDepends: libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libpam-runtime but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libpam-modules but it is not going to be installed
 ncurses-bin : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
               PreDepends: libtinfo6 (>= 6.3) but it is not going to be installed
 perl-base : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.35) but it is not installable
 sed : PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23) but it is not going to be installed
       PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
       PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 sysvinit-utils : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 tar : PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23) but it is not going to be installed
       PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
       PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 util-linux : PreDepends: libblkid1 (>= 2.37.2) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
              PreDepends: libcap-ng0 (>= 0.7.9) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libmount1 (>= 2.38) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libsmartcols1 (>= 2.38) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libsystemd0
              PreDepends: libtinfo6 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: util-linux-extra
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo apt-repository install libc6:i386
sudo: apt-repository: command not found
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo apt  install libc6:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gpgv or
                gpgv2 but it is not going to be installed or
                gpgv1
       Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: raspbian-archive-keyring but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
       Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.5) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libseccomp2 (>= 2.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsystemd0
       Recommends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
 base-files : PreDepends: awk
 base-passwd : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
               Depends: libdebconfclient0 (>= 0.145) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 bash : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.36) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: libtinfo6 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
 bsdutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
            PreDepends: libsystemd0
            Recommends: bsdextrautils
 coreutils : PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libattr1 (>= 1:2.4.44) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
             PreDepends: libgmp10 (>= 2:6.2.1+dfsg1) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 dash : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 debianutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 diffutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 dpkg : PreDepends: libbz2-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: liblzma5 (>= 5.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libmd0 (>= 0.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libzstd1 (>= 1.5.2) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
 e2fsprogs : PreDepends: libblkid1 (>= 2.36) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
             PreDepends: libcom-err2 (>= 1.43.9) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libext2fs2 (= 1.47.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libss2 (>= 1.38) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: logsave
             Recommends: e2fsprogs-l10n but it is not going to be installed
 findutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
             PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 grep : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: libpcre2-8-0 (>= 10.32) but it is not going to be installed
 gzip : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but it is not installable
 hostname : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv or
                    sysvinit-core but it is not installable
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.36) but it is not installable
            Depends: libc6 (< 2.37) but it is not installable
 libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libidn2-0:i386 (>= 2.0.5~) but it is not going to be installed
 libcrypt1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.36) but it is not installable
 libgcc-s1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 login : PreDepends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
         PreDepends: libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libpam-runtime but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libpam-modules but it is not going to be installed
 ncurses-bin : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
               PreDepends: libtinfo6 (>= 6.3) but it is not going to be installed
 perl-base : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.35) but it is not installable
 sed : PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23) but it is not going to be installed
       PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
       PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 sysvinit-utils : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 tar : PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23) but it is not going to be installed
       PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
       PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 util-linux : PreDepends: libblkid1 (>= 2.37.2) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
              PreDepends: libcap-ng0 (>= 0.7.9) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libmount1 (>= 2.38) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libsmartcols1 (>= 2.38) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libsystemd0
              PreDepends: libtinfo6 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: util-linux-extra
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: apart from the problem at hand, how do you imaging running `i386` binaries on `arm64` processor such as the RPi5? (`amd64` can run `i386` code natively, but `arm64` cannot (it can run `armhf` code though))